# How to override the 85% windows() screen size setting in R?

Tags: r, settings

I have a multi-monitor computer, and I want to open in an specific monitor, in full screen, any new graphic device generated by the function windows().

I found a program called [MultiMonitor tool](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/multi_monitor_tool.html) that gives me the coordinates of each monitor (I could not figure out any other way to get those coordinates). Then I enter the coordinates of the monitor I want to display on in the options xpos and y pos of the windows() function. That sets the position of the new graphic device on the selected monitor.

To make the graphic device/window maximized, I enter as width and height the resolution of the one monitor. The generated new window appears in the chosen monitor, but at a smaller size. I try multiple configurations of the options in the windows() function without success.

```
windows(width=1920, height=1080, xpos=3840, ypos=0, rescale="fit")
```

I think this smaller size has to do with a comment in the help information of the windows() function, saying that any new graphic device by the windows function is 85% of the monitor size. Is there anywhere in R where that setting can be modified?

I found a promising file called "graphapp" located at "C:\Program Files\R\R-4.1.0\include"

in that file there is a set of commands for the windows called "Window creation flags", with several options:

```
 #define Resize     0x00000080L
 #define Maximize   0x00000100L
 #define CanvasSize 0x00200000L
 #define StandardWindow (Titlebar|Closebox|Resize|Maximize|Minimize)
```

Any insight will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I discover that after creating the new graphic device, one can run the line of code:

```
msgWindow(type="maximize")
```

and that maximizes the active window.